# Html: How to access outer javascript code from an iframe

Tags: javascript

Before i explain the problem please understand that i am **not** trying to access a DOM element but rather some js code from inside the iframe.

Consider my structure

```
<body>
    <script>
      class PlayerClient{
          constructor(){
              alert('Successfuly called')
          }
      }
    </script>

 <section id="The-Big-Picture">
    <iframe src="/app/explore/sp/home" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="91%">
        Sorry your browser does not support inline frames.
    </iframe>
 </section>
</body>
```

This iframe is `SAMEORIGIN` and all i'm trying todo is to instantiate the `class PlayerClient` from **inside** the iframe like so `new window.parent.PlayerClient()`. Why would i want to do this? Because i found it to be DRYer declaring the class in one location only.

Here is an image of the HTML structure[image]

The blue highlight returns `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you can't access `window.PlayerClient` even in the parent window. In this aspect, `class` is just like `let` or `const`, unlike `var`. You can get the explanation as `Global constants do not become properties of the window object, unlike var variables.`
go https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Answer (score 0):

Could that be because scripts haven't been loaded yet in the parent window?

Comment: I guess it's not the case if your script is inline though.